Right click > "Open with..." button does not show the selection dialog
When I right click a .tif file and press "Open with...", the context menu closes but the "Open File" dialog does not show. Doing the same with a .json file opens the dialog as expected.
What could be the issue? It did not show any error message to explain what happend.

Restarting my computer fixed it
